# Firestore: reference type.How wait for all get() call of evey result

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fork-join, reference-type

I am getting an Observable Ticket[]>  from a firestore DB, one field in ticket is reference type.

When I subscribe for results I use:

```
 getTickets()
.subscribe(listOfTickets=> {  

     //loop the array
     listOfTickets.forEach(ticket => {

         ticket.personRef.get()  //this is the reference type field
         .then(res => { //getting information
            let person = res.data();
       }
     }         
     .... 
 }
```

How can I wait for all the results in:

```
ticket.personRef.get()
```

I am trying using forkJoin, but I still do not understand how apply to this. The observable listOfTickets has a lot of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `forEach`. Use `for`

```
  async someFunction() {
    getTickets().subscribe(async listOfTickets => {
      const allTickets = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < listOfTickets.length; i++) {
          await listOfTickets [i].personRef.get().then(snapshot => {
            return snapshot.data();
          }).then(ticket => {
            allTickets.push(ticket);
          })
        }
      console.log(allTickets);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your help point me in the right direction to solve the problem with just some little changes, this is the final code:

```
async someFunction() {
  getTickets()
  .subscribe(async listOfTickets => {
    const allTickets = [];
    var ticket = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < listOfTickets.length; i++) {

      await listOfTickets[i].personRef.get().then(snapshot => {
        ticket = snapshot.data();
      })

      allTickets.push(ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know you sorted it out considering that I blotched my answer a little. Should have read it more carefully.